# How to capture no response with a lambda Alexa trivia skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am creating a timed trivia skill and I want the user to run out of time after the 8 second response time and for the game to mark that question as wrong.

However, I can't find a way for the sessionEndedRequest to not result in the skill shutting down or any alternatives.

Does anyone know how to capture a 'no response' and continue the session with the user?